# $C^k$ one-parameter family of metrics

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

Consider a smooth Riemannian manifold $M$ and a $C^k$ one-parameter family of Riemannian metrics $g_t$ on $M$. Here $k$ could be any integer, $k$ could be infinity, when the one-parameter family $g_t$ is smooth in time, or $k = \omega$, when the one-parameter family $g_t$ is real analytic in time. Now, as the metric varies, the Laplacian associated to the metric varies, and hence its spectrum also varies in time. My question is, if $g_t$ is $C^k$ in time, are the eigenvalues of the Laplacian also $C^k$ in time for $k$ integer, $k = \infty$ or $k = \omega$? In case such results are well-known (which I am assuming they are), what is a good reference to learn about such results? Thanks for any guidance.

Edit after Umberto Lupo's answer: I was somewhat more interested in the compact case, which Umberto's answer and the paper he cites cover very nicely. I would, however, be highly interested in learning about possible results in the non-compact setting as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The references given in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179122/behavior-of-the-spectrum-of-the-laplacian-under-pointed-smooth-convergence/179776#179776) to a related issue provide at least a partial answer to your question.

On a *complete* Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, the Laplacian associated with $g$ is essentially self-adjoint on $C_0^\infty(M) \subset L^2(M)$. If $M$ is also *compact*, then its resolvent is also a compact operator.  Therefore, under these two additional assumptions you will satisfy the hypotheses of the main theorem on page 1 in the second article linked there:

- Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor, Armin Rainer: Denjoy-Carleman differentiable perturbation of polynomials and unbounded operators. Integral Equations and Operator Theory 71,3 (2011), 407-416. ([pdf](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/DC-perturb.pdf)).

Cases (A)-(F) and (N) answer your question at a selection of regularity scales. I hope this helps.